# MVC5 Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic

Ive been working on converting a MVC4 project over to MVC5. The first day I ran into an 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' but was able to resolve it by starting my conversion over. I'm not sure what the fix was which is a bummer, because its happened again.

The Error occurs in _ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml when I load the Login.cshtml page. The error is thrown on line 15. (string action = Model.Action;)

```
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security

@{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    var authenticationDescriptions = loginProviders as AuthenticationDescription[] ?? loginProviders.ToArray();
    if (!authenticationDescriptions.Any())
    {
        <div>
            <p>There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313242">this article</a>
            for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.</p>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        string action = Model.Action;
        string returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl;
        using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in authenticationDescriptions)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default padded-8 margin-8" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" 
                            value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">

                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Brands/"+p.Caption+".png")" alt="Microsoft" class="img-responsive" />
                        <br/>
                        <b>@p.Caption</b>
                    </button>
                }
                </p>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

The error thrown is

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Action'

The snapshot says

> Message : object' does not contain a definition for 'Action'
>   Source : Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly

Now this is double weird because when I set a breakpoint Model.Action is not null. I can see the value.

This is really frustrating. The app was working 5 min ago.. I had changed the html on a non related page.. and now it wont work.

**Hackish Fix**
I would rather know why this error is happening. That said, I have a quick fix in case anyone else comes across this (***Because this is part of part of the default solution***). The solution is to not use dynamics. Create your own viewmodel and pass that.

```
  public class ExternalLoginViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "ReturnUrl")]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}

 @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Action = "ExternalLogin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

Comment: I having the exact same issue. Pretty weird.

Comment: I managed to get around the issue by simply passing the action string on its own and using ViewBag.ReturnUrl direct within the _ExternalLoginsListPartial - rather than creating a new ViewModel.

Comment: Did you figure out what the underlying issue is? I remember I had that issue as well, but it was because my ViewModels weren't being referenced in the cshtml correctly; but now it's occurring again, and I can't figure out whats wrong!

Comment: No I did not. I wish I did, but suspect this may be a bug. I have moved on.... The work arounds published by par and myself work.

Comment: The way I fixed it before was that I had to completely clean the solution and build agian; however that doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: This is most certainly a bug because I have changed absolutely nothing in my project and it "just broke" from outta nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is verified by Microsoft, and they are working on fixing it.

So anyone from the future who reads this: try updating visual studio 2013 to at least update 2.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813133/bug-in-mvc-5-framework-asp-net-identity-modules

Answer (score 4):

Check the views in the Account folder and for each one that has an explicit model, make sure the (view)model is in the right namespace. Mouse over the m parameter (m => m.UserName ... etc) and make sure it is referencing the correct  (view)model.
In my case, I moved AccountViewModels to a different folder and the app broke as above. It appears the views are sort of "caching" the model from the original namespace. I used a silly fix (commented out the @model line and un-commented it back). Got warning that m is dynamic but when built and ran it worked. Looks like a glitch in VS 2013 RTM.

Comment: My namespaces are correct. The error occurs in a partial view without a model.

Comment: @nVentimiglia - the error happens in this line: string action = Model.Action of _ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml file and Model.Action has the correct value in debug. Check views that have models and make sure their m parameters are correct (even if they compile ok).

Comment: Confirm my namespaces are correct.... That said I commented out my model declaration and the problem disappeared.

That said, I had a broken version of the project (before my fix above) saved. I can confirm the project models are default, in the correct namespace and with a valid model declaration in Login.cshtml.

Comment: I had this issue and, after fixing the bad namespace, I had to shut down IIS Express and start debugging again before it started working.

Comment: This resolved the same issue for me on VS2012 (update 3), note that I previously created the explicit view model (ExternalLoginViewModel) that nVentimiglia suggests, but after fixing a different view in the Accounts folder where the model namespace was wrong, I then reverted back to using a dynamic model for the _ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml view and it all worked ok.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for my own (mvc5) project after some experimenting.

I had a `_ExternalLoginsListShoppingCartPartial.cshtml` (from my mvc4 project) with `@model ICollection<AuthenticationClientData>` at the top. I commented it out and rebuild the solution and suddenly it works. I'm not even using that partial view in any view so it's a pretty nasty bug imo.

So check in your project. You may have some mvc4/simplemembership stuff that is messing up your mvc5 project.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after replacing account models to another folder. When I double checked each view under the Account folder I found out my "Manage.cshtml" referenced to old namespace. I changed it to correct namespace for my models and the error fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had changed the contents of the ManageUserViewModel to add a property... I then started getting the error. When I changed the Manage.cshtml from not using an explicit model to using:

@model XYZ.Models.ManageUserViewModel

and removed the using statements, it started working again. One hour wasted!

Answer (score 1):

I also hit this issue with VS 2013 U3. I had just added an email field to RegisterViewModel with the [EmailAddress] attribute, and it was crashing when I tried visiting the Register page. Commenting out the [EmailAddress] attribute fixed the issue. However, it continued working after I added the attribute back in, so this is probably a broader issue that could have to do with changes to the model classes.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I replaced the "else" code with the following and its working but still trying to see why it didn't work when using Model.Action ?

```
//string action = Model.Action;
//string returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl;
//using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }))
using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

Comment: This is useless if you want to reuse the view with multiple actions (As the initial internet project [and mine] does). It is not addressing the underlying problem.

Comment: I got this fixed  (string action = Model.Action;) is working fine for me , i rechecked all the models in cshtmls those are used in login and registration functionality and I found my problem fix in Register.cshtml.BTW i got this issue while upgrading from MVC 4 to MVC 5.

Comment: And the solution was ?