# .NET and Java Script Exceptions in fresh new ASP .NET MVC 5 Web application in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, it has Update 1 installed. 
The problem I am dealing with is I get many exceptions when I run **new** Web Application. The application starts but there is big mess in the output. It is new application so it is probably not my fault.

`Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript:` means `Runtime error in JavaScript`.

After update to Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 these are left.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 27877 in http://localhost:4530/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 28093 in http://localhost:4530/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60610 in http://localhost:4620/f17552bcff2e4111a7debf6f82a3f7c5/browserLink
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
```

Comment: Have you tried to run VS as Administrator?

Comment: @Freerider Great. Two first exceptions disappeared, rest is still there. I posted them again in EDIT to original post to clarify current situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Visual Studio 2013 it has been fixed in Update 2.

More information on [MSDN](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813133/bug-in-mvc-5-framework-asp-net-identity-modules).

You can also read this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626425/mvc5-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-runtimebinderexception) post.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954531/lots-of-first-chance-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinderexceptions-thrown-when-dealin) might also be helpful.

Comment: Does those exceptions make something essential not working? I know this is not clear question. Does beside those outputs I can get something essential like Entity Framework not fetching data or similar?

Comment: It should not "break" anything no.

To remove them when compiling follow these steps:
1) From the Debug menu, select Exceptions.
2) Click the "Add..." button on the bottom right.
3) Choose "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" from the Type dropdown.
4) Type "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" as the name.
5) Click OK.
6) The exception type will now appear on the list.  Just deselect it.

Comment: I found out that I already have Update 2 installed now I Installed Update 3 and in OP there are errows which are left.

Comment: Try to create a new project now that you have Update 3 installed.

Comment: Yes, I did : ). Those errors in updated post are from new project created after Update 3.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in my comment above?

Comment: No I did not because AFAIK it only hides them not solves them. They still will be thrown just not printed on the output.

Comment: My only other suggestion is cleaning the solution and rebuilding. Read more here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813133/bug-in-mvc-5-framework-asp-net-identity-modules